# WHERE IN Query with two recordsets in Access VBA

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba, recordset

My first post here, so i hope this is the right area. I am currently trying to compare 2 recordsets, one of which has come from an Excel named range, and the other from a table in the Access database. The code for each is:

```
Set existingUserIDs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Username FROM UserData")
Set IDsToImport = exceldb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Username FROM Named_Range")
```

The problem is that I would like to somehow compare these two recordsets, without looping (there is a very large number of records). Is there any way to do a join or similar on these recordsets?

I can not do a join before creating the recordsets, due to the fact that one is coming from Excel, and the other from Access, so they are two different DAO databases.

The end goal is that I will choose only the usernames that do not already exist in the access table to be imported (so in an SQL query, it would be a NOT IN(table)).

Thanks for any assistance you can lend!

Regards,
Bricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare data from two different sources in one query. You can either use the IN keyword in SQL or, more simply, link to the Excel table (sheet) in Access and build your query around that.

EDIT an example using IN

```
SELECT * FROM  CompareTable 
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]  
    IN ''[Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:\Full\Path\AndName.xls]) C
ON CompareTable.CourseKey=c.CourseKey
WHERE c.CourseKey Is Null
```

Sheet1$ can also be Named_Range.

Comment: I know that I can compare two different sources in the same database (e.g. if they were both in the Excel sheet, or were both in the Access database) - but how do I query two different sources in two different databases (like the example above)?

Comment: Link the Excel table to the Access database. In versions prior to 2007, choose File->Get External Data->Link table.

Comment: I have added an example using IN.