# How to check Excel time values in Access VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm processing an Excel workbook with Access VBA (see [Reading an Excel workbook from Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304224/)) and now I want to check if a cell contains a valid time value. For dates I use IsDate() and it works fine.

But with time values it doesn't (since there is no IsTime() I also use IsDate() for time values). Or should I use IsNumeric because time values are stored as doubles?

With " 12:00:00" (with space) IsDate() gives TRUE (!?) but Excel itself doesn't recognize it as a time value, the VBA debugger also shows it as a text string.

With "12:00:00" IsDate() gives FALSE but Excel itself recognize it as a time value, the VBA debugger shows the value 0,5.

Anybody?

UPDATE 9/12:

Thanks to @belisarius and @mwolfe02 I found this for my situation:

```
/* Valid time value */
IsDate() = False,
IsNumeric() = True,
TypeName() = Double

/* Numeric (no time) value */
IsDate() = False,
IsNumeric() = True,
TypeName() = Double

/* Valid date value */
IsDate() = True,
IsNumeric() = False,
TypeName() = Date

/* Invalid time value (e.g. with leading space as in above example) */
IsDate() = True,
IsNumeric() = False,
TypeName() = String
```

So I only need to check if `TypeName()` returns `Double` and `IsNumeric() True` and to avoid confusion with 'normal' numeric values if the value is >= 0 and < 1. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different concepts:

**1) Date & Time format**

When you format a cell in Excel to contain date (and/or) time, Excel uses an internal representation. According to MS:
*By default, January 1, 1900 is serial number 1, and January 1, 2008 is serial number 39448 because it is 39,448 days after January 1, 1900. Microsoft Excel for the Macintosh uses a different date system as its default. 
Numbers to the right of the decimal point in the serial number represent the time; numbers to the left represent the date. For example, the serial number .5 represents the time 12:00 noon.*

And that is it. Dates and times are stored as decimal numbers.

**2) Things that VBA *could* convert to a Date/Time**

This is what IsDate checks. According to MS:

*Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an expression can be converted to a date.*
A True returned by IsDate does not mean that a cell has been formatted as Date/Time, it just tells you that you *may* convert this value to a date/time. But worse: the function may return different values for different platforms:  *In Microsoft Windows, the range of valid dates is January 1, 100 A.D. through December 31, 9999 A.D.; the ranges vary among operating systems.*

What is clear is that Excel did not validate the contents of the cell as a date/time. It's almost sure a text containing whatever characters the user typed in (as the space in your example). The IsDate() return is telling you that **VBA** is not able to convert the value to a date, but perhaps you can, if you know the format (and write an ad-hoc function for the conversion).

HTH!

**Edit** 
I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338025/isdate-function-returns-unexpected-results) may help you too.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I still don't fully understand the issue but for my situation I've got the right information (I think), I will add my findings as an answer to my question