# SQL state 22005 Access

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to insert a new line in Ms Access.

The fields are the following

[image: Design]

And this is my query

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO [Meldungen] VALUES ('',".$_SESSION['Firma_Index'].",'01.01.2001',".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",0,'Internet')";
```

I always get mismatch of data type SQL state 22005. But I already deleted the '-s for the number things and text still got the ''. Any idea? God, I hate this cryptic error messages.

Comment: Is `$password` a number?

Answer (score 0):

Literal date values in MS Access (technically, the Jet/ACE db engine) must be enclosed in `#` signs, not double or single quotes.  Also, [Access interprets periods (`.`) as *time* separators, not *date* separators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4338025/154439).  I believe it disregards regional settings when doing this, though, admittedly, I'm not sure.

Try the following instead:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO [Meldungen] VALUES ('',".$_SESSION['Firma_Index'].",#01/01/2001#,".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",".$password.",0,'Internet')";
```