# Add user-defined function (UDF) to built-in category in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

When I add a public function to a standard code module in Excel it shows up in the Insert Function wizard in the catch-all category "User Defined."

Is there any way to:

1. Keep the function public (so it may be called from other modules) but hide it from the Excel function wizard?
2. Make the function appear in a built-in category (e.g., "Financial", "Statistical", "Logical")?
3. Create my own category (e.g., "Nonsensical") and have my function appear there?

I only need to be able to make one of the above cases work, but I'd be curious to know if each one is possible.

*Note: I will gladly split this into three separate questions if the community feels that is more appropriate.  I am thinking there may be a single answer with only slight variation among the three questions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.MacroOptions` is the command you are after

This example adds a user-defined macro called **TestMacro** to a custom category named **My Custom Category**.

```
Function TestMacro()
    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Function

Sub AddUDFToCustomCategory()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="TestMacro", Category:="My Custom Category"
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't work as you've written it.  Category is looking for an integer.  From the help file: ***Category***  Optional **Variant**. An integer that specifies the macro function category (Financial, Date & Time, or User Defined, for example).

Comment: Category can also take a string, and if it doesn't match a built in definition, it will create a new category

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, because I get a "Runtime error '1004': Method 'MacroOptions' of object '_Application' failed" when I try to run it with a string.  If I pass an integer (e.g., 1) it runs successfully.

Comment: perhaps it's version dependent. I'm using Excel 2007

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm testing on Excel 2002.

Comment: @mwolfe02: For integer values see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209988%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> *Is there any way to [...] Keep the function public (so it may be called from other modules) but hide it from the Excel function wizard?*

Put `Option Private Module` at the top of your module. Done.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266185(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I answered this in a foonote to [a question about VBA Date functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338025/isdate-function-returns-unexpected-results/11143379#11143379): here's a straight copy-and-paste of what I wrote there, on using VB 'Attribute' statements to create function descriptions *and a Function Wizard category ID*:

> **A Tip for people still using Excel 2003:**
>
> If you (or your users) are going to call IsDateEx() from a worksheet,
>   put these two lines in, immediately below the function header, using a
>   text editor in an exported .bas file and reimporting the file, because
>   VB Attributes are useful, but they are not accessible to the code
>   editor in Excel's VBA IDE:
>
> `Attribute IsDateEx.VB_Description = "Returns TRUE if TestDate
>   is a date, and is within ± 20 years of the system date.\r\nChange the
>   defaulte default ± 20 years boundaries by setting values for
>   LimitPastDays and LimitFutureDays\r\nIf you are checking an array of
>   dates, ALL the values will be tested: set FirstColumnOnly TRUE to
>   check the leftmost column only."`
>
> That's all one line: watch
>   out for line-breaks inserted by the browser! ...And this line, which
>   puts isDateEX into the function Wizard in the 'Information' category,
>   alongside ISNUMBER(), ISERR(), ISTEXT() and so on:
>
> `Attribute IsDateEx.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "w\n9"`
>
> Use "w\n2" if you prefer to see it under the Date & Time functions:
>   beats hell outta losing it in the morass of 'Used Defined' functions
>   from your own code, and all those third-party add-ins developed by
>   people who don't do quite enough to help occasional users.
>
> I have no idea whether this still works in Office 2010.

...And that's all I can suggest. Function Wizard categories and the associated function (and parameter!) descriptors aren't really accessible to VBA developers. Some of this is available to old-school VB coders, who have access in their IDE to VB.Attribute statements; and you can sort-of slip it into your code with a bit of text file manipulation.

Comment: +1 This is excellent info for Excel pre-2007.  I marked the other answer as accepted because it should work for more people going forward.  I appreciate you taking the time to post this, though, because it's difficult information to come by.

Answer (score 2):

Public Functions are only visible to Excel's formula bar is they reside in a "regular" *.bas Module. Public Functions belonging to classes are not visible to the formula bar. If you add this together with the fact that we can simulate a static class, you can effectively hide functions.

If you create a class module and then export it, you will find `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False` in the header. Setting this to true creates a default global instance of the class that can be used much like a static class in a more modern language.

For example, create a new class module named `Math` and add this function to it.

```
Public Function Add(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Long
    Add = a + b
End Function
```

Export and remove the file, then open it in notepad. Change the predeclared Id to true.

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Math"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
```

Save and Import the file back into your project.

Now, in a regular module, you can call the function with a qualified call. Just like any other class method. Only now, we have a default instance of the class to work with. There's no mucking around with `New` or `Set`, it just works.

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Math.Add(1,2)
End Test
```