# IsDate validates wrong format

Tags: asp-classic

I have these lines

```
SetLocale(3081)
Response.Write "<p>TEST: " & Date() & " | " & isDate("3/22/2014") & " --> " & GetLocale() & "</p>"
```

which outputs

> TEST: 3/07/2014 | True --> 3081

now correct me if i'm wrong but isn't there **only 12 months in a year**?, according to `IsDate` the date i've passed, which should be wrong because i have put in 22 as the month, is valid despite the local settings saying otherwise.

i want to validate the date to be the correct format to insert into the database and if it isn't give a more friendly error, "3/22/2014" will output "Error converting data type varchar to date." when i try to inster it into the database because it's getting by the IsDate check

What have i done wrong here?

Comment: Can you try using `Session.LCID = 3081` instead of `setLocale` ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ done that, no difference, `GetLocale()`/`Session.LCID` return whatever the i set using `Session.LCID`/`SetLocale(#)` so the `response.write` confirms the locale setting and the format `Date()` is coming out as

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338025/isdate-function-returns-unexpected-results)[Please check if you can use anything from  this thread]

Comment: @SearchAndResQ: You've got to be really careful when assuming that the script version of any VB command is the same as the equivalent VB6, VBA or VB.NET command - basically most of them aren't.  As a fail safe for dates I always use the `dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` format (obviously excluding the time if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed a valid date.

Why? Because VBScript is smart/generous/stupid (choose your favorite) enough to treat numbers as dates. And "3/22/2014" can be parsed as formula: 3 / 22 / 2014 = 6.770786313983931e-5

Now take this number and convert to date:

```
Dim myNumber, myDate
myNumber = 6.770786313983931e-5
myDate = CDate(myNumber)
```

The variable `myDate` will be perfectly valid date, which is December 30<sup>th</sup> 1899, 00:00:06

So bottom line: the value is a date, just not what you expect. You've done nothing wrong, but to really check if a string is valid date you will have to check it yourself, no out of the box methods.