# Print dates in proper format

Tags: vba, date, datetime, excel

I have an excel workbook with many dates.

- On the worksheet they are in a format of "mm/dd/yy hh:mm"
- What I see in the white box above the sheet is in the format of "dd/mm/yy hh:mm"

I need to print the worksheets into text files, but when I do so, it's printing in the format of `dd/mm/yy hh:mm`, Instead of `mm/dd/yy hh:mm`.

Here's the code:

```
         For i = 1 To LastRow
            For j = 1 To LastCol
                If j = LastCol Then
                    DataLine = DataLine + Trim(Cells(i, j).Value)
                Else
                    DataLine = DataLine + Trim(Cells(i, j).Value) + vbTab
                End If
            Next j

            If (DataLine <> "") Then
                Print #FileNum, DataLine
                DataLine = ""
            End If
        Next i
```

Does any one has an idea how to print the sheets in the format I need?

Comment: Try using **.Text** and not **.Value** when you retrieve cell contents.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent `.Text` can be unreliable, as it will return garbage `#####` when the column is not wide enough to display the date, etc.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett _____________You are correct!_________I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Format` function to customize the text formatting of dates.

I escaped the forward slash `/` because otherwise it is interpreted as the date separator and "The actual character used as the date separator in formatted output is determined by your system settings" (from documentation). With escaping, it should always output a `/` character.

```
Format(Cells(1, 1).Value, "MM\/dd\/yy hh:mm")
```

Comment: + 1 Yup that would be the right way :) Also OP needs to use `&` instead of `+`

Comment: @bouvierr - I noticed now that it's converting regular numbers into dates also... how can I check the cell format?

Comment: @Bramat: That depends on what you need. you can use `IsDate(x)` to check if it's a date or a string that **looks** like a date. You can also use `VarType(x) = vbDate` to check if a value is **stored** as a date. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338025/isdate-function-returns-unexpected-results) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Format(Cells(i,j), "mm/dd/yy hh:mm")` to do this

Or what might work better is you could use

```
Cells(i,j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "dd/mm/yy hh:mm")
```

This would return a text variable instead of datetime.

Comment: Why resort to Excel's `TEXT` worksheetfunction when VBA's native `Format` does the job?

Comment: Because in Excel the Text worksheetfunction returns as a text variable instead of a date variable (Like OP requested). However for some reason in VBA it is returning it as a date variable still. My mistake